# incompatible akka-http versions with elasticmq version

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

im trying to run sqs server using elasticmq-rest-sqs:

```
"org.elasticmq" %% "elasticmq-rest-sqs" % "0.14.7"
```

and my akka dependencies are:

```
  val akka = Seq(
    "com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-sns" % "0.15",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.8" % Test withSources(),
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.5.8" % Test withSources(),
    "com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-sqs" % "0.15"
  )
```

now in my test im writing:

```
 // sqs server
  val sqsServer: SQSRestServer = SQSRestServerBuilder.withPort(4576).withInterface("localhost").start()
  sqsServer.waitUntilStarted()
```

and i get the following error:

> A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your
>   runpath. Missing class: akka/http/impl/util/SettingsCompanion
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/http/impl/util/SettingsCompanion

its versioning thing for sure since im using it the same way in another project, but with play 2.6 (not sure if it has anything to do with it)

if im downgrading elasticmq version i get this error:

> An exception or error caused a run to abort:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   akka/http/scaladsl/settings/RoutingSettings 
>   java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   akka/http/scaladsl/settings/RoutingSettings

please help :/

Comment: any updates on this? Since i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following version is working: (also matched this problem but fixed it with version)

```
    "org.elasticmq" %% "elasticmq-rest-sqs" % "0.15.2" 



"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.8" % Test withSources(),
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % "2.5.8" % Test withSources(),
"com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-sqs" % alpakkaVersion
```

val alpakkaVersion = "**1.0-M2**"

and:

```
"com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.2"
```